# .NET Core - cannot run file with external dll

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-assembly

Consider I have .net core (netcoreapp1.1) csproj file:

```
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="CQRS">
      <HintPath>..\..\libs\cqrs\CQRS.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="CQRS.RawRabbit">
      <HintPath>..\..\libs\cqrs\CQRS.RawRabbit.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
...
```

I can run `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` commands - everything compiles fine (all types from referenced assemblies are resolved). The problem is with running app: `dotnet run`. The speciied error is thrown:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'CQRS.RawRabbit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. Cannot find the file specified.

I have tried to use `<Private>` node (copy local). Despite the assmebly files is inside bin folder, somehow app cannot find it. What is wrong?

Comment: use `dotnet publish` first to get a full application ready to run. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish

Comment: @Gusman tried. No luck. I can't even debug app.

Comment: but have you tried the publish, went to the publication folder and then did `dotnet run yourdll.dll`?

Comment: Yes. The same error occurs.

Comment: Are the libraries copied to the publish folder?

Comment: Yes, they are inside publish folder. There were compiled as .NET Stnadard Library 1.5

Comment: Very strange as the error explicitly says it's not found... Let me check the package, will be back in 5 minutes.

Comment: Ok, you are trying to use a package which is not compatible with .net Core, the package CQRS is not .net Core nor .net Standard and uses a library called cmdotnet which is also not compatible.

Comment: How do you know? CQRS.dll is our internal company libary compiled as .NET Standatd 1.5, has no dependencies. That is why it is references as dll not nuget package.

Comment: Well, I assumed it was the available package on NuGet as there exists one package with the exact same name... may be a coincidence...